# Generic sort of linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, generics, linked-list

I'm trying to write a generic sort function for a linked list in C, based on the max sort algorithm.

I'm currently testing the function on strings, with my compareFunction being "strcmp", so the data should be ordered in descending lexicographic order.

The initial data of the list is: Chupakabra, Beach, Sandstorm, Dog, Bark.

Then, after 1 iteration of the while loop in my sort function I get Sandstorm, Beach, Sandstorm, Dog, Bark.

However, according to the printfs "findGreatest" returns correct values at exit, and so does "swap".

Can anyone please help me find the problem with my sort function?

```
ListResult listSort(List list, CompareListElements compareElement){
    if(!list || !compareElement){
        return LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }
    if (HEAD == NULL || HEAD->next == NULL){
        return LIST_SUCCESS;
    }
    ListNode head = HEAD;
    ListNode greatest;
    while (head){
        greatest = findGreatest (head, list, compareElement);
        if (greatest == NULL){
            return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        }
        printf("Head data before swap: %s\n", (char*)head->data);
        printf("Greatest data before swap: %s\n", (char*)greatest->data);
        swap(&(head->data), &(greatest->data));
        printf("New head data: %s\n", (char*)head->data);
        printf("New greatest data: %s\n", (char*)greatest->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Struct, swap & helper function definitions:

```
#define ITER list->iter
#define NEXT list->next
#define HEAD list->head

typedef struct ListNode {
    ListElement data;
    struct ListNode* next;
} *ListNode;

struct List_t {
    ListNode head;
    CopyListElement copyElement;
    FreeListElement freeElement;
    ListNode iter;
};

void swap (ListElement* element1, ListElement* element2){
    ListElement* temp = *element1;
    *element1 = *element2;
    *element2 = temp;
}

ListNode findGreatest (ListNode head, List list, CompareListElements compareElement){
    ListNode greatest = malloc(sizeof(*greatest));
    ListNode current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
    if (greatest == NULL || current == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    greatest->data = head->data;
    greatest->next = head->next;
    current->data = head->data;
    current->next = head->next;
    while (current){
        if (compareElement(greatest->data, current->data) > 0){
            greatest->data = current->data;
            greatest->next = current->next;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    free(current);
    return greatest;
}
```

I've tested the swap function from main and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please include a full program: What is `List`definition? What is `findGreatest()` definition?

Comment: We'll probably need to see your `swap` definition as well, since it seems like it's replacing instead of swapping.

Comment: `ListNode head = HEAD;` (--> like as `ListNode head = list->head;`) ? also `findGreatest (head, list, compareElement);` --> `findGreatest (head, compareElement);` ?

Comment: I've added the macro & List definitions to the post. CompareElement is a pointer to a function that does the comparison (in this particular case it's strcmp, but could be anything).

Comment: `ListElement* temp = *element1;` --> `ListElement temp = *element1;` also `findGreatest` return clone of element, not element of list.

Comment: and `current = current->next;` at `findGreatest` : memory leak. (`free(current);` is `free(NULL);`)

Comment: If I change the swap to     swap(head->data, greatest->data);  I get a very weird output when I print the list: 
Sandakabra
Beach
Chupstorm
Dog
Bark.
Seems like the program replaces only part of the word.

And if I remove the dynamic allocations of greatest and current in findGreatest and just initialize both to "head" before entering the loop, both current & greatest are the same at the exit of findGreatest all the nodes before the one with "greatest" data get erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list : `Chupakabra, Beach, Sandstorm, Dog, Bark`
first time `greatest` element is `Sandstorm`.
head element swap to `Sandstorm` element, but your `findGreatest` return clone.
So
&(`Sandstorm`->data) != &greatest->data Because `greatest` has been newly allocated.
(So you get `Sandstorm, Beach, Sandstorm, Dog, Bark`)

So try this

```
void swap (ListElement* element1, ListElement* element2){
    ListElement temp = *element1;//element1 dereference type is ListElement
    *element1 = *element2;
    *element2 = temp;
}

ListNode findGreatest (ListNode head, CompareListElements compareElement){// "List list," unused list
    ListNode greatest = head;
    ListNode current;

    if (greatest == NULL || greatest->next == NULL){
        return greatest;
    }
    current = head->next;
    while (current){
        if (compareElement(greatest->data, current->data) > 0){
            greatest = current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and seems to be much simpler than what I wrote with all the dynamic allocations.

Comment: @Alice312 accept this answer if the problem is resolved.